# Added fields in quick edit screen need to update at the moment

Tags: wp-admin

I have added the meta fields in quick edit screen in wordpress admin section. When Isave the quick edit screen, it will be saved but not shown at cuurent time but when I reload the page it will show the updated data.

I think there is ajax issue is there

```
 // Add to our admin_init function

add_filter('manage_schedule_posts_columns', 'myown_add_post_columns');

function myown_add_post_columns($columns) {
    $columns['stime'] = 'Start Time';
   $columns['etime'] = 'End Time';
    return $columns;
}

// Add to our admin_init function

add_action('manage_schedule_posts_custom_column', 'myown_render_post_columns', 10, 2);

function myown_render_post_columns($column_name, $id) {
    switch ($column_name) {
    case 'stime':
        // show my_field
        echo get_post_meta( $id, 'stime', TRUE);

case 'etime':
        // show my_field
        $my_fieldvalue1 = get_post_meta( $id, 'etime', TRUE);
        echo $my_fieldvalue1;
    }
}

// Add to our admin_init function

add_action('quick_edit_custom_box',  'myown_add_quick_edit', 10, 2);

function myown_add_quick_edit($column_name, $post_type) {
    if ($column_name != 'stime') return;
    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-left">
        <div class="inline-edit-col">
            <span class="title">start time</span>
            <input id="myfield_noncename" type="hidden" name="myfield_noncename" value="" />
            <input id="myfield" type="text" name="stime" value=""/></br>
         <span class="title">End time</span>
       <input id="myfield1" type="text" name="etime" value=""/></br>
        <div id="main">
         <span class="title">Add New Session date</span></br>
       <a href="#" class="aclick">Add new</a></br></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
     <?php
}

// Add to our admin_init function 

add_action('save_post', 'myown_save_quick_edit_data');   

function myown_save_quick_edit_data($post_id) {     
  // verify if this is an auto save routine.         
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )          
      return $post_id;         
  // Check permissions     
  if ( 'stime' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {         
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )             
      return $post_id;     
  } 
if ( 'etime' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {         
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )             
      return $post_id;     
  } 
else {         
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )         
    return $post_id;     
  }        
if(isset($_POST['tag-name']))
{
 if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if ( $post->post_type == 'schedule') { // change 'post' to any cpt you want to target
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $post->post_name, 'schedule_category');
    if ( empty($term) ) {
      $add = wp_insert_term( $_POST['tag-name'], 'schedule_category', array('slug'=> $_POST['tag-name']) );
      if ( is_array($add) && isset($add['term_id']) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $add['term_id'], 'schedule_category', true );
      }
    }
  }
}

 // Authentication passed now we save the data   

  if (isset($_POST['stime']) && ($post->post_type != 'revision')) {
        $my_fieldvalue = esc_attr($_POST['stime']);
        if ($my_fieldvalue)
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'stime', $my_fieldvalue);
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'stime');
    }
    return $my_fieldvalue;
 if (isset($_POST['etime']) && ($post->post_type != 'revision')) {
        $my_fieldvalue1 = esc_attr($_POST['etime']);
        if ($my_fieldvalue1)
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'etime', $my_fieldvalue1);
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'etime');
    }
    return $my_fieldvalue1;
}

// Add to our admin_init function

add_action('admin_footer', 'myown_quick_edit_javascript');

function myown_quick_edit_javascript() {
    global $current_screen;
    if (($current_screen->post_type != 'schedule')) return;

    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".aclick").one("click", function(){  
   jQuery("#main").append('<input type="text" name="tag-name" />');
});
});
function set_myfield_value(fieldValue,fieldValue1, nonce) {
        // refresh the quick menu properly
        inlineEditPost.revert();
        console.log(fieldValue);
        console.log(fieldValue1);
        jQuery('#myfield').val(fieldValue);
         jQuery('#myfield1').val(fieldValue1);
}
</script>
 <?php 
}

// Add to our admin_init function 

add_filter('post_row_actions', 'myown_expand_quick_edit_link', 10, 2);   
function myown_expand_quick_edit_link($actions, $post) {     
    global $current_screen;     
    if (($current_screen->post_type != 'schedule')) 
        return $actions;
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'myfield_'.$post->ID);
    $myfielvalue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'stime', TRUE);
    $myfielvalue1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'etime', TRUE);
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] = '<a href="#" class="editinline" title="';     
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] .= esc_attr( __( 'Edit this item inline' ) ) . '"';
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] .= " onclick=\"set_myfield_value('{$myfielvalue}','{$myfielvalue1}')\" >";
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] .= __( 'Quick Edit' );
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] .= '</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: What is your question, and please clean up your code, it is an unreadable mess

Comment: Thanks for your response.
My question is this :-
I have added the meta fields in quick edit screen in wordpress admin section. when i save the quick edit screen. it will be saved but not shown at cuurent time but when i reload the page it will show the updated data. i think there is ajax issue is there.?

Comment: This should be **inside** your question, not a comment. File an [edit] and add your comment in your question, and please, clean up your code, no one can read it

Comment: Now the code is readable. please check it.

Comment: Yes, because I have edited it. Still, I ask what is your question. Please reread my previous comment. Your question **should not** be is a comment, but **inside** your question

Comment: But it is saying your question is no more than 150 characters. :(

Comment: I have added your comment as as an edit. Please take your time and read through [this section](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on how to edit your posts. Also see [ask] and visit [help] and learn how to ask a good proper question which will recieve good feedback